# Entity Framework, Database First - Change how a Table Column is Returned to Web Application

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Database First, and I have a table which has two columns encrypted. 
When the data is requested from the web app, I want that information to be dencrypted.

Is there any way using entity framework to integrate this operation globally, so i don't have to do it in various locations?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the model class look like?

Comment: You can do it it using the EF generated partial class. You can add a new partial class extending the existing EF generated class and add new properties for Decrypted data.

Comment: Thanks Agalo. In this case i'll will need to change the name of that property throughout the project. Is there a way to use the same property? Maybe something like overriding the binding of the property with a custom operation?

Comment: The model class is just a class with various string properties

Comment: Is the data transfered over the web?

Comment: You can change the code in EF generated partial class also. but the downside is that each time you update the Database model, it will recreate the classes and you will loose your changes.

Comment: Data is not transferred over the web. If it did, it would be decrypted. Why are you asking?